# how I can make the scroll in this case just below the line in android by java

Tags: java, android, android-scrollview

[this image of the activity that I am working on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srBpm.png)

[I want the scroll start form here below the View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8XzR.png)

[this is my 2 RelativeLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp0Qa.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scrollview inside the main layout (e.g. ConstraintLayout or RelativeLayout) which also contains the topview.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
 ...">

    <TextView
       ....
        />

    <ScrollView
       ....
        >

        <LinearLayout
           .... />
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: it did not work Mr T i have 2 nested relativeLayout and i need the scrollView inside the second relativeLayout 
i did it but it didn't work Mr T i hope if you can help me

Comment: Without a code it is hard to find the reason for your problem. You can also can use [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/widget/NestedScrollView)

Comment: Ok Mr T thank u 
last question Pls
how i can make any TextView as a selected item and its dependent on the user 
i am trying to do it like that 
the border black in first click 
the border gray in second click 
i don't know how i can do it 
by the way the default border is gray
the item is ( upload license ) in my image .
 and if there is any way to share you my code Pls

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
 <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout_first"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        
        <!--Your 1st layout components here-->

    </RelativeLayout>
    
    <ScrollView
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/relative_layout_first"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <!--Your 2nd layout components here-->
            
        </RelativeLayout>
        
    </ScrollView>
    
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>`